# Entering scores to be placed in 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The program prompts the user for 4 players. It then is supposed to ask the user to enter 10 scores for each player. Currently the way my code is, it asks for 10 scores for the first player then moves to the second and asks for the 10 scores and so on. I need help on getting the program to ask the user to enter in a score for the player at [0] then at [1] and so on until 10 scores have been recorded for each player. If that sounds confusing I can clear anything up. Here is what I have so far.

```
package bowling;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bowling {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_ENDS = 10;
    private static String[] player = new String[4];
    private static int[][] scores = new int[4][NUMBER_OF_ENDS];

    public static void addPlayer() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int counter = 0; counter < player.length; counter++) {
            System.out.println("Enter player #" + counter + " name");
            player[counter] = input.nextLine();

        }

    }

    public static void addScores() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int counter = 0; counter < player.length; counter++) {
            for (int inner = 0; inner < NUMBER_OF_ENDS; inner++) {
                System.out.print("Enter the score for " + player[counter]+"---->");
                scores[counter][inner] = input.nextInt();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this class would be much much simpler if you just used a single data structure called a hashmap<String, int[]>

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Seems like he is a student just learning to code and may not be familiar with hashmap yet.

Comment: Yes, we have not been taught what hashmap is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you already have the logic, no? If I'm understanding correctly, you want the console output like this:

```
Enter the first score for player 0:
Enter the first score for player 1:
Enter the first score for player 2:
Enter the first score for player 3:
Enter the second score for player 0:
Enter the second score for player 1:
Enter the second score for player 2:
Enter the second score for player 3:
etc...
```

instead of like this?

```
Enter the first score for player 0:
Enter the second score for player 0:
Enter the third score for player 0:
etc...
Enter the first score for player 1:
Enter the second score for player 1:
Enter the third score for player 1:
etc..
```

If so, that would simply mean switching the inner and outer for loops like this:

```
for (int inner = 0; inner < NUMBER_OF_ENDS; inner++) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < player.length; counter++) {

            System.out.print("Enter score number " + (inner + 1) + " score for " + player[counter]+"---->");
            scores[counter][inner] = input.nextInt();

        }
    }
```

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you have it so that the program asks for the scores for one player, then moves on to the next, and you want it to input a score for a player, then move on to the next player, and repeat the process. If so, then all you need to do is switch the for loops in your addScores method.

```
for (int inner = 0; inner < NUMBER_OF_ENDS; inner++) {
    for (int counter = 0; counter < player.length; counter++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the score for " + player[counter]+"---->");
        scores[counter][inner] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```